# Prove by induction that $5^n - 1$ is divisible by $4$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, induction, divisibility

> Prove by induction that $5^n - 1$ is divisible by $4$.

How should I use induction in this problem. Do you have any hints for solving this problem?

Thank you so much.

Comment: What do you know about the question or what have you tried?

Comment: I have a vague feeling that this question has already been covered on the site.

Answer (score 13):

We prove that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $4 \mid \left( 5^n-1 \right)$. (Notationally, this says $4$ divides $5^n-1$ with a zero remainder).

1. For a basis, let $n=1$. Then
   $$5^1-1=4,$$
   and clearly $4\mid4$.
2. Assume that $5^n-1$ is is divisible by $4$ for $n=k, \, k \in\mathbb{N}$. Then by this assumption,
   $$4 \mid \left( 5^k-1 \right) \Rightarrow 5^k-1=4m, \, m \in \mathbb{Z}.$$
   (This notationally means that $5^k-1$ is an integer multiple of $4$.)
3. Let $n=k+1$. Then
   $$
   \begin{align*}
   5^{k+1}-1 &= 5^k \cdot 5-1 \\
   &=5^k(4+1)-1 \\
   &=4\cdot 5^k+5^k -1 \\
   &=4\cdot5^k+4m\\
   &=4\left( 5^k+m \right).
   \end{align*}
   $$
   Since $4\mid4\left( 5^k+m \right)$, we may conclude, by the axiom of induction, that the property holds for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Nice, clear, clean... a good answer indeed!

Comment: this should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 12):

First prove the base case $n=1$. Then induct and make use of the fact that
$$(5^{n+1}-1) - (5^n-1) = 4 \cdot 5^n$$to conclude what you want.

Answer (score 7):

Without induction, you can use the identity

$$a^n-1=(a-1)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}+...+a+1)$$

Of course you would still need induction or something to prove this identity.

Comment: Yes. I removed my comment once I saw your updated answer. To be really pedantic, even in my answer, we still need induction first to show that $5^n$ is an integer, to then claim that $4$ divides $4 \cdot 5^n$.

Answer (score 5):

without induction
$$5^n-1=(4+1)^n-1$$
$$=4^n+n4^{n-2}+...+1-1$$
the only term in $(1+4)^n$ not being multiplied by a power of $4$ is $1$ but it disappears due to the $-1$.

Answer (score 4):

Why induction? $5^n$ ends in $\dots25$ for $n>1$, so $5^n-1$ ends in $\dots24$.

Comment: Technically, you still need induction to show that $5^n$ ends in $25$ for $n>1$.

Comment: @user17762 $25 * 5 = 25 \mod 100$

Comment: @ratchetfreak Technically I think you still need induction to prove the statement about an arbitrary $n$.  Of course, using the fact you mention, the induction becomes trivial (like proving by induction that $1^n = 1$ for all $n$ using the fact that 1 is the multiplicative identity.)

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle{5^{n + 1} - 1 = \left(5^{n} - 1\right)5 + 4}$

Answer (score 1):

it's even more general:

$k$ divides $(k+1)^n-1$ with $k,n \in \mathbb{N}$

simply by modular arithmetic:

$$k+1 = 1 \mod {k} \\
\Downarrow \\(k+1)^n=1 \mod {k}$$

Answer (score 1):

To prove by induction you:

1. Assume the proposition is true for n
2. Show that *if* it is true for n, then it is also true for n+1
3. Show that it is true for n=1

Then you know that it will be true for all natural numbers.

In this case:

1. Assume $5^n-1$ is divisible by 4
2. Say $m=5^n$, so $m-1$ is divisible by 4

   - $5^{n+1}-1$ = $5m - 1$
   - $5m - 1$ = $5(m-1) + 4$
   - Since $m-1$ is divisible by 4 and 4 is divisible by 4, then this expression is divisible by 4.
3. For $n=1$, $5^1 - 1 = 4$ which is divisible by 4

And there you are...

Answer (score 1):

This isn't by induction, but I think it's a nice proof nonetheless, certainly more enlightening: $\displaystyle 5^n-1=(1+4)^n-1=\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}4^k-1=1+\sum_{k=1}^n {n\choose k}4^k-1=\sum_{k=1}^n {n\choose k}4^k$ which is clearly divisible by $4$.